# I want to test IGMP capability of a OpenWRT based router. How caan i test?

Tags: networking, multicast, testing, openwrt, igmp

This is what I want to test out,
[SEE IMAGE: Router connected to users and is accessible over the internet as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7u6S.png)

1. PC1 and PC2 should be able to join some group(s).
2. Should be able to leave group as well.
3. When joined they should receive the multicast UDP traffic.

What tool should I use to test out?

PC1 and PC2 are Ubuntu or any GNU/Linux-based PC.

I've tried ostinato but that is only one way and isn't dynamic and for some reason, its older version 0.9 isn't working anymore.

Please help

Comment: Is there any application like dvblast(except I want to source a local file instead of the TV signal) , that can be used to generate the traffic and I can use the vlc media on the other computer? That might work, right?

Comment: http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-multicast.html